# Adjusting brake rub on a mini-v brake (Giant Propel)

Tags: brakes

I have a Giant Propel and the front left brake is constantly rubbing and sticking against the wheel. I've tried adjusting the bolt highlighted below, which I believe is the spring tension, but loosening or tightening this bolt seems to do nothing.

[image]

I've also tried adjusting the barrel adjuster but when I loosen it, the right side (which isn't rubbing) will move further out from the wheel, where as the left side (the one that's rubbing) won't move at all no matter how much I twist the barrel.

Does anyone know how to centre these brakes to prevent them rubbing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The small screw to the northwest of your red circle in the picture is the spring tension adjuster. Tighten it down to increase the pull on the left side.

You may also want to loosen the screw on the right side if there is a large imbalance in tension between the two arms.

The bolt you tried adjusting simply holds the brake arm on. It doesn't have anything to do with the adjustment of your brake.

Comment: Generally, you want to start both arms at the least tension possible and then increase tensions until you balance them.

Comment: Make sure you retighten the bolt in the red circle as it is the mounting bolt that attaches it to the fork.

Comment: Thanks guys, this did the trick. I was a bit confused because I was going by this document, and that bolt isn't present: https://www.giant-bicycles.com/_upload_in/Propel%20Brake%20Setup%20Tips.pdf

Comment: It's not labelled on the photo of the parts, but it's shown in the drawing for 
"5. Center the brake arms by turning the spring tension screw (align to seat
stay)" on page 4.

Comment: @suskie don't forget to mark this as correct answer:)